# mongodb schema design for ProductSchema and ReviewSchema

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections: product & review
I initially decided not to nest reviews in product schema because the number of reviews can get quite large. And I also need to query reviews independently for the admins to see.

When a user visits the product page, I can "join" the product and corresponding recent twenty reviews(pagination, 20 per page for example) in the backend server and return it to the client. Now this is an "sql" like method and it works totally fine.

But then I thought, how about only nesting the recent twenty reviews. These nested reviews will also be stored as individual review documents. Now this causes twenty duplications and more updates. But products & reviews are more read intensive, and this way could reduce the read speed almost by half. (Instead of two database requests, we only have single request)

Please share your opinions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving review references inside the products collection will cause an update to the product document everytime a new review is made for the that document. Also products will have lots of other fields, so there is no need to make it have more fields.

I would suggest parent referencing here. There will be no reviews references inside the products collection, but we will keep product reference inside the review collection. When a review is made for a product, we just need a simple insert inside the reviews collection.

We also need to think about the user who makes a review for the product. So we need to keep a user reference inside the review collection.

Let me show some sample  documents for these collections:

products:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4bdffb09d2675c3cdf8371"),
    "name" : "Product1",
    "price" : 1
}
```

users:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4bdfa809d2675c3cdf8370"),
    "username" : "User1",
}
```

reviews: (User1 made a review for Product1)

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e4be86809d2675c3cdf8387"),
  "reviewDate": ISODate("2020-02-18T15:51:22.584+03:00"),
  "product": ObjectId("5e4bdffb09d2675c3cdf8371"),
  "user": ObjectId("5e4be85d09d2675c3cdf8386"),
  "score": 5
}
```

And we can read the product info and it's reviews and the user of the review in one db access using mongodb aggregation framework. So it is not a big issue.

For example: [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OUtk-FW2skn)

```js
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("5e4bdffb09d2675c3cdf8371")
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "reviews",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "product",
      as: "reviews"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$reviews"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "reviews.reviewDate": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "reviews.user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "reviews.user": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$user",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      user: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      reviews: {
        "$push": "$reviews"
      },
      "doc": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$doc",
          {
            "reviews": "$reviews"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This will give a result in the following way:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e4bdffb09d2675c3cdf8371"),
    "name": "Product1",
    "price": 1,
    "reviews": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e4be83b09d2675c3cdf8381"),
        "product": ObjectId("5e4bdffb09d2675c3cdf8371"),
        "reviewDate": ISODate("2020-02-18T16:15:22.584Z"),
        "score": 2,
        "user": {
          "_id": ObjectId("5e4be83009d2675c3cdf8380"),
          "username": "User8"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e4be09709d2675c3cdf8375"),
        "product": ObjectId("5e4bdffb09d2675c3cdf8371"),
        "reviewDate": ISODate("2020-02-18T15:02:22.584Z"),
        "score": 4,
        "user": {
          "_id": ObjectId("5e4be08b09d2675c3cdf8374"),
          "username": "User2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e4be84b09d2675c3cdf8383"),
        "product": ObjectId("5e4bdffb09d2675c3cdf8371"),
        "reviewDate": ISODate("2020-02-18T14:08:22.584Z"),
        "score": 3,
        "user": {
          "_id": ObjectId("5e4be84109d2675c3cdf8382"),
          "username": "User9"
        }
      },
    ...
    ]
  }
]
```

With this, when you open a GET api for the product detail page, this will contain all the information you will need.